# How to deploy to jetty's container?

Tags: jetty

I have an application i can war up which i usually use with tomcat in an exploded-ear configuration.

How can i get it to work most painlessly with jetty? I am finding the documentation a bit ambiguous in this area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a context file with the same name as your web application WAR file inside the `$JETTY_HOME/contexts` directory.

[test.xml](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ContextDeployer)

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
<set name="contextPath">/test</set>
<set name="war"><systemproperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps/test.war</set>
</configure>
```

Put your WAR file in `$JETTY_HOME/webapps/test.war`

Start Jetty from the command line by calling

```
java -jar start.jar
```

when in the home Jetty directory.

Comment: Starting with Jetty 9.1, it is advised to deploy your application in `$JETTY_BASE/webapps/test.war` instead of `$JETTY_HOME/webapps/test.war`. You can read more here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/quickstart-running-jetty.html